# Is a Team Provisioning Profile enough for development?

Tags: ios, certificate, provisioning-profile

As a developer in my team, Is a Team Provisioning Profile enough for development ?
In other words, Need I a development profile further to develop and test for my team?

Because I just have the Technical role in my team, so for me troublesome to add new profiles.
I have to ask admins to do so who are too busy to do such operations.

It will be good if a Team Provisioning Profile is enough for development for me.

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Team Provisioning Profile is sufficient if you are just doing development that don't involve some of the specialized iOS features (i.e. iCloud Storage, Push Notifications, In-App Purchases, Game Center).  If you aren't doing any of this, then the Team Profile will suffice for development/debugging.  A separate distribution profile will need to be created when it comes time to actually publish the app though.

Comment: Thanks so much for Gambit's prompt reply! I do need to test In-App Purchases function soon. I just post a question before I saw your reply: https://devforums.apple.com/message/717200#717200

Comment: Now my problem is that, the App ( whose APP ID is associated with my Team Provisioning Profile ) is unavailable for its In_APP_Purchase. The other App ID ( whose In_APP_Purchase is Enabled with green button ) is NOT associated with my Team Provisioning Profile. But The other App ID is exact what I want to develop and test. Its Provisioning Profile has expired. Because I was just joined this team and take over the technical role in the Provisioning portal, How I can associate my Team Provisioning Profile to the other APP ID that has In_APP_Purchase enabled and is exact what I want to dev on?

Comment: Or how to activate the expired Provisioning Profile and add me as that profile? Which is the simplest way because , as a technical role,I have to ask admins who are too busy to do it for me. thanks!

Comment: If you need to use the In-App Purchase feature, then the team provisioning profile will not do it for you. However, it sounds like your team agent has already created a provisioning profile and an App ID. With only the team member role, you will not have the ability to renew the profile and add yourself to the profile. The Team Agent or Team Admin will need to do it for you.